# Play video from new URL without creating a new AVPlayer object

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to allow users to be able to cycle through videos, changing the AVPlayer URL on the fly without refreshing the view. However, right now I'm just instantiating AVPlayer objects every time a video is played (resulting in audio to be played over one another), which I feel isn't the best way to do this. Is there a more efficient way similar to changing the image in an imageView?

This is the code where I play the clip:

```
player = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer!.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
player!.play()
```

Answer (score 27):

Do not use an `AVPlayer`.

Instead use an `AVQueuePlayer` which allows you to insert and remove items from a queue.

```
//create local player in setup methods
self.localPlayer = AVQueuePlayer.init()
```

to add items you can simply use

```
//optional: clear current queue if playing straight away
self.localPlayer.removeAllItems()

//get url of track
let url : URL? = URL.init(string: "http://urlOfItem")
if url != nil {
   let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url!)

   //you can use the after property to insert 
   //it at a specific location or leave it nil
   self.localPlayer.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
   self.localPlayer.play()
}
```

`AVQueuePlayer` supports all of the functionality of the `AVPlayer` but has the added functionality of adding and removing items from a queue.

Answer (score 4):

Use AVPlayerItem to add and remove outputs to an AVPlayer object.

Instead of adding a video to the AVPlayer when you create it, create an empty AVPlayer instance, and then use the addOutput method of the AVPlayerItem class to add the video.

To remove the video and add a new one, use the removeOutput method of the AVPlayerItem class to remove the old video, and then the addOutput method again to insert the new one.

Sample code is available from Apple's developer site at;

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Introduction/Intro.html

It provides the same thing I would, were I to post code of my own.

Comment: I ask because I can't instantiate the AVPlayerItem without a URL or an AVAsset. I wouldn't be able to access the fileURL variable in viewDidLoad where I'd set up the AVPlayer.

Comment: Import the Photos framework, and then, wherever you have been loading a AVPlayerItem or an AVAsset, use instead [[PHImageManager defaultManager]  request...[choose either playerItem or asset];

Comment: @JamesBush you should still show the code, even if it's Apple's

Answer (score -1):

Create AVPlayer Instance globally then override it again when you want to play a new video from new URL.

Answer (score -2):

I am able to accomplish what you are looking for by doing this...

I  have a tableView of song names, for which the mp3 files are stored on Parse.com. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I do...

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    SelectedSongNumber = indexPath.row
    grabSong()
}


   func grabSong () {

    let songQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    songQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block: {
        (object: PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in


        if let audioFile = object?["SongFile"] as? PFFile {
            let audioFileUrlString: String = audioFile.url!
            let audioFileUrl = NSURL(string: audioFileUrlString)!

            myAVPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: audioFileUrl)
            myAVPlayer.play()

            currentUser?.setObject(audioFileUrlString, forKey: "CurrentSongURL")
            currentUser?.saveInBackground()
        }
    }) 
 }
```

when I run this, i select a row and the song starts playing. If i then wait a few seconds and select a different row, the AVPlayer plays the song from the new cell that i selected and does NOT play one song over the other. My AVPlayer is declared as a public variable for all classes to see.

Comment: As I said, don't access the AVPlayer object after you create; rather, work only with its currentItem.

Comment: @JamesBush Indeed yours is a better method. Another option is to use an AVQueuePlayer, add all the possible URL's an AVPlayerItems array and then insert that array into the queue and re-order the array on the fly. This will allow the next video in line to begin buffering while previous video is still playing

Comment: Or:
[self.player prerollAtRate:1.0 completionHandler:^(BOOL finished) {

[self.player play];

[self.player setRate:1.0];

}];